# "Geometric" Decomposition of Wiener Space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, stochastic-processes, wiener-measure

Let $C_0([0,1];\mathbb{R}^d)$ be the classical Wiener space (of continuous paths with initial value $0$) and let $\nu$ be the Wiener measure on this space.  Does there exist a countable family $\left\{U_n\right\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of open subsets of $C_0([0,1];\mathbb{R}^d)$ such that

- $\nu(U_n)= \frac1{2^n}$
- $U_n \cap U_m=\emptyset$ if $n\neq m$
- $\nu\left( C_0([0,1];\mathbb{R}^d) - \cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} U_n\right) =0$

Comment: Since $\nu$ is a probability measure then $K_n\triangleq \nu^{-1}[\frac1{2}^n,\frac1{2}^n-\frac1{2}^{n+1}]$ is $\nu$-measureable and of $\nu$ measure $\frac1{2^n}$.  Since $\nu$ is an *outer-*regular Borel measure then there are open subsets $U_n^k$ satisfying

 - $\nu(U_n^k)\leq \nu(U_n^{k+1})\mapsto \nu(K_n)$
 - $K_n\subseteq U_n^k$.  

Some more work probably shows the result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For natural $n$, let 
$$U_n:=\{x=(x_1,\dots,x_d)\in C_0([0,1];\mathbb{R}^d)\colon \Phi(x_1(1))\in\delta_n\},
$$
where $\Phi$ is the standard normal pdf and $\delta_n:=(1-1/2^{n-1},1-1/2^n)$. Then the family $(U_n)$ has all the desired properties.

---

Indeed,

(i) for each natural $n$, the set $U_n$ is open, because $\delta_n$ is open;

(ii) the $U_n$'s are disjoint, because the $\delta_n$'s are disjoint;

(iii) 
$$\nu(U_n)=P(\Phi(B(1))\in\delta_n)=1/2^n,
$$
where $B$ is the standard Brownian motion -- because $\Phi(B(1))$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$;

(iv) the property $\nu(C_0([0,1];\mathbb{R}^d)-\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} U_n)=0$ follows immediately from (ii) and (iii).

Comment: Thank you Iosif, this is very helpful.